# Displaying data from a CSV file with multi-dimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, csv, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to pull data from a CSV file that contains vehicle make, model, mileage etc...

**Using this example from php -**

```
<?php 
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('csv/csvin.csv'));
array_walk($csv, function(&$a) use ($csv) {
    $a = array_combine($csv[0], $a);
});

array_shift($csv);

foreach($csv as $car){
    foreach($car as $key=>$value){
        echo "<div id='car'>".$key.":".$value."</div></br>";
    }
}
?>
```

**This is the array I get -**

```
BodyStyle:"Station Wagon"

"DaysInStock":"27"

"Make":"Toyota"

"Model":"Prius v"

"MSRP":"0"

"SellingPrice":"26995"

"StockNumber":"387515"

"Trim":"Three"

"VIN":"JTDZN3EU9E3306528"

"Year" :"2014"
```

Now when I attempt to manipulate it or pull any individual values I simply cannot.  How would I go about displaying this information with HTML tags for each value?

I have tried this:

```
print_r ($csv[0]['Make']; 
echo $csv[0]['Make'];
```

Just to try and display a value but still nothing. I noticed for some reason the "BodyStyle" doesn't contain quotes like the rest so something definitely seems fishy.

From here how would I strip the quotes and break out each value?

**This is the error being thrown - 
Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($csv as $car){
    echo "<tr><td>Make:</td><td>".$car['Make']."</td></tr>";
}
```

alternatively:

```
foreach($csv as $car){
    foreach($car as $key=>$value){
        echo "<tr><td>".$key."</td><td>".$value."</td></tr>";
    }
}
```

alternatively:

```
echo $csv[0]['Make'];
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! The 2nd alternative here is the only one that got me a step closer, I now have a cleaner array - BodyStyle"Station Wagon""DaysInStock""27""Make""Toyota""Model""Prius v""MSRP""0""SellingPrice""26995""StockNumber""387515""Trim""Three""VIN""JTDZN3EU9E3306528""Year" "2014" From here how would I strip the quotes and break out each value?

Comment: I would suggest updating your question with what you've got now. It will help further diagnose the problem.

Comment: @RyanD I looked at your updated question. Try replacing the second `foreach` loop (the entire thing) with `echo $car['Make'];`. Theoretically, this should produce `"Toyota"`. If this is what occurs, then the first answer I provided (non-alternates) is the way you want to go, and you will just need to do some string manipulation (e.g. `echo str_replace('"','',$car['Make']);`

Comment: Thanks again @Richard Theobald but still nothing, not real sure why as it seems it should work..

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
print_r ($csv[0]['Make']);
```

Basically the $csv variable is an array, to get its values you have to use the loop function, something like :

```
foreach ($csv as $data) {
    foreach ($data as $index => $value) {
        if ($index == "make") {
            echo $value;
        }
    }
}
```

If you notice it a bit, the outer array is called indexed array (array with indexes) and to traverse the values use foreach ($csv as $data), while the inner array is called associative array (this array does not use number as index, but a name), and to traverse it use foreach ($data as $index => $value).
Try it and you'll see :)
PS: Sorry I didn't notice the inner array, for this case Richard's answer is the correct one. I have added a credit to his answer for giving a correct answer.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! I tried these and still nothing.. Seems logical and that it should work though..

Comment: Thanks again but still having trouble with this, what your saying makes sense but when I try and implement that method I get nothing..For whatever reason I cannot call out the individual values in anyway..

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out that I only need 1 foreach loop like so -

```
foreach($csv as $car){
    $type = $car[0];
    $echo $type;
}
```

Works now and thanks all for the help!